# How to fix this problem with clean method in forms.ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm doing a application to upload Images. I need validation of one of two fields. By file or by url. I wrote such code, but the view method does not call clean_image in forms.py. Thanks for the help (sorry for my bad English)

## forms.py

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    url = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'image',
            'url'
        )

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        url = self.cleaned_data.get('url')
        if (image != None and url != '') or (image == None and url == ''):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Fill one field')

    def save(self):
        self.clean_image()
        new_image = Image.objects.create(
            image=self.cleaned_data.get('image'),
            url=self.cleaned_data.get('url')
        )
        return new_image
```

## views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            upload_form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        upload_form = UploadForm()
    context = {
        'form': upload_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'upload_page.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [**`clean()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    image = cleaned_data.get('image')
    url = cleaned_data.get('url')
    if not image and not url:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Fill either url or image field')
    return cleaned_data
```

And update template to show error:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```